My Az cli what-if for a bicep deployment at Management scope is not showing the change at the nested management group
So I have a bicep deployment file that creates a subscription and passes the subscription ID to another bicep file that targets management group scope to deploy resourcegroup and the other resource.
when I run a what-if to see changes, I see only the changes at the scope of the bicep file that deploys the subscription.

az deployment mg what-if --name 'name' --management-group-id '$(mgmtgroupid)' --location"$(location)" --    template-file '.A.bicep' 

biceps look like this
** A.bicep**
 targetScope = 'managementGroup'

       module subAlias './modules/subscription.bicep' = {
         name: 'create-${subscriptionAlias}'
          params: {
              billingAccount: billingAccount
             subscriptionAlias: subscriptionAlias
              subscriptionDisplayName: subscriptionDisplayName
               subscriptionWorkload: environmentconfigurationMap[environment].subscriptionWorkload
          }
       }

     module createResourceGroupStorage 'B.bicep' = {
      name: 'nested-createResources-${subscriptionDisplayName}'
       params:{
           subID : subAlias.output.subscriptionID  
         }
     


B.bicep
        targetScope = 'managementGroup'

       {{other modules that deploy resourcesgroup and other resources}}


Expecting to see the changes from the nested deployment happening in B.bicep and not just that happening in A.bicep
example is below but  it is a Subscription scoped deployment.


In what authorization scope your ARM service connection was established, subscription or management group? Are your using Azure CLI task to deploy your bicep templates? Can you please share a minimal reproducible YAML pipeline definition and bicep templates to help understand your workflow? please don't forget to remove any sensitive or private information such as token, password, certificate, IP etc. since the community is visible to public. Thx.

have you actually deployed your bicep files? I don't think it will work successfully

I did. It works perfectly. I can see from the portal, the deployments under the respective management groups, resource groups etc But when I try to update a property of a resource and run the what-if I don’t see the changes about to be made and that’s troubling and precarious.

what-if not really reliable tbh: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73760427/4167200

Hi @kossytony, if you run the az deployment mg what-if commadn locally would the results be the same?

@Alvin technically it should still be the same. But I will give it a try.

Hi @kossytony, Yes I agree. Please let us know your local test results to help us isolate the cause of the issue, as you are reaching out to the subcommunity of Azure DevOps. Thx.

Hi @kossytony, I have reproduced your issue with some simplified templates in my answer below. The issue is more likely irrelevant to Azure DevOps pipeline agent environment or authorization scope of the ARM service connection. Hope the findings may help resolve your concerns in this post. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT tried the answer by hardcoding the subID to the B.bicep and it worked, the question now is, how do I pass the value of the output from the subscription module to the B.bicep as a parameter value ?

@kossytony, Per your follow-up query, may I assume you have decided to create a new sub for 1st deployment, and after the completion of 1st actual deployment, you will be able to retrieve the actual output subID for the preview of another deployment with az deployment mg what if command?

@kossytony, I have updated the answer regarding your query how do I pass the value of the output from the subscription module to the B.bicep as a parameter value. Hope it helps to resolve the issue in this post. Good luck and happy weekends.

Thanks @AlvinZhao-MSFT.. Happy weekend to you too. I am using a yaml pipeline that runs the what-if task first , then runs the deployment task. Please recall that the subscription creation happens in the same bicep that has a module that consumes the subscription ID in the what-if run.

@kossytony, Please recall the information in my answer, what-if command cannot generate a valid subID for downstream module to consume, because it can only preview the deployment rather than make any changes to the existing resources; however, the deployment in B.bicep requires a valid subID to preview, which is the root cause of the issue that you are unable to see the new resources to be deployed given your original bicep template. And again, please note this behavior is the same no matter you run what-if in local PowerShell or in a pipeline task.

Therefore, due to the limit of the what-if command, your expectation to preview the deployment of new sub creation and other dependent resources in the same template is not possible. We have to retrieve the valid subID after the succeeded subscription creation, so that the what-if command can preview the resources to be deployed in B.bicep.

This was also why I suggested you consider separating the workflow into 2 deployments; to Run mg what-if to preview the creation of the sub -> create the new sub for 1st deployment and output the subscriptionId; then to Run mg what-if again passing the value of output subscriptionId as the subID parameter to complete downstream preview and deployment. I am not so familiar with Azure CLI as Azure DevOps, but hope the findings may help. Cheers.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT thanks you. you pointed me in the right direction. your suggestion will solve my issue.

Update
Per your follow-up query,

Tried the answer by hardcoding the subID to the B.bicep and it worked; the question now is, how do I pass the value of the output from the subscription module to the B.bicep as a parameter value ?

If you prefer Azure CLI tool, after you succeed in creating a new subscription with the subscription module, you can use the az deployment mg show command to retrieve the valid subscriptionId output from 1stARMDeployment-CreateNewSub and then pass it into the B.bicep as a parameter value for 2ndARMDeployment-CreateResourcesFromB.
Add output subscriptionId string = subAlias.outputs.subscriptionId in A.bicep;
targetScope = 'managementGroup'

module subAlias './modules/subscription.bicep' = {
  name: 'create-${subscriptionAlias}'
  params: {
    billingAccount: billingAccount
    subscriptionAlias: subscriptionAlias
    subscriptionDisplayName: subscriptionDisplayName
    subscriptionWorkload: environmentconfigurationMap[environment].subscriptionWorkload
  }
}

output subscriptionId string = subAlias.outputs.subscriptionId

PowerShell
$newSubID = $(az deployment mg show --name '1stARMDeployment-CreateNewSub' --management-group-id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' --query properties.outputs.subscriptionId.value)

az deployment mg what-if --name '2ndARMDeployment-CreateResourcesFromB' --management-group-id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' --location "southeast asia" --template-file 'B.bicep' --parameters subID=$newSubID



Based on your description, I managed to reproduce the issue via local PowerShell with the sample bicep templates below.
A.bicep
param subscriptionDisplayName string = 'Azure Subscription ARM1'
param subscriptionAlias string = 'subARM1'
param billingAccount string = '/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/123456/enrollmentAccounts/654321'
param environment string = 'Prod'
param environmentconfigurationMap object= {
  Prod: {
    subscriptionWorkload: 'Production'
  }
}

targetScope = 'managementGroup'

module subAlias './modules/subscription.bicep' = {
  name: 'create-${subscriptionAlias}'
  params: {
    billingAccount: billingAccount
    subscriptionAlias: subscriptionAlias
    subscriptionDisplayName: subscriptionDisplayName
    subscriptionWorkload: environmentconfigurationMap[environment].subscriptionWorkload
  }
}

module createResourceGroupStorage 'B.bicep' = {
  name: 'nested-createResources-${subscriptionDisplayName}'
  params:{
      subID : subAlias.outputs.subscriptionId // Require a valid subID
    }
}

/modules/subscription.bicep
targetScope = 'managementGroup'

@description('BillingAccount used for subscription billing')
param billingAccount string

@description('Alias to assign to the subscription')
param subscriptionAlias string

@description('Display name for the subscription')
param subscriptionDisplayName string

@description('Workload type for the subscription')
param subscriptionWorkload string

resource alias 'Microsoft.Subscription/aliases@2020-09-01' = {
  scope: tenant()
  name: subscriptionAlias
  properties: {
    workload: subscriptionWorkload
    displayName: subscriptionDisplayName
    billingScope: billingAccount
  }
}

output subscriptionId string = alias.properties.subscriptionId


B.bicep
targetScope = 'managementGroup'

@description('subscriptionId for the deployment')
param subID string

@description('Name of the resourceGroup, will be created in the same location as the deployment.')
param resourceGroupName string = 'rg-armdemo'

@description('Location for the deployments and the resources')
param location string = deployment().location

// deploy to the subscription and create the resourceGroup
module rg './modules/resourcegroup.bicep' = {
  scope: subscription(subID)
  name: 'create-${resourceGroupName}'
  params: {
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroupName
    location: location
  }
}

/modules/resourcegroup.bicep
targetScope = 'subscription'

@description('Name of the resourceGroup.')
param resourceGroupName string

param location string = deployment().location

resource rg 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
}


If directly using a string of subID instead of the outputs from the upstream module, the what-if command was able to preview the resources to be deployed in B.bicep. The behavior is by-design, since the what-if command can only preview the changes in a deployment rather than make any changes to existing resources. Besides, the resource for deployment in B.bicep requires to use a valid subID, while what-if command doesn't output such a value.

Regarding the Scope concern, it should be consistent with the deployment scope of each resource to be deployed. Taking my C.bicep template below to create a new management group for example, its scope was the same as that of a new subscription in A.bicep but different from that of a new resource group in B.bicep.

